# Magmi Root Category Creation

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magmi

I have one store (base) and I need to create another root category to test a new strucutre out so my plan was to create a new Root Category and then tell magmi to import into that... No such luck.

I've created a new root category called `Testing`.

Here is a sample of the Data.

```
sku,categories
12345, [Testing]/Level1;;[Testing]/Level1/Level2;;[Testing]/Level1/Level2/Level3
Every time I try and import this, I get this error:
```

On the fly category creator/importer v0.2.5 - Cannot find site root with names : Testing,Testing,Testing

Can anyone help me out with this one?

Answer (score 0):

As i seen you are messed the store column.

**If you want to add root level category you must have to defined store name**

```
store,sku,categories
yourstoreviewcodeforInternalUse,A115,[Internal Use]::test1::test
```